# Jquery append not working outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Hi I want to just add the group ID to the start of the web page, I'm trying to append it to the div "test", and then add a space - allow it to pull data from the yammer API, and then loop through groups with a separation including the group ID. Can anyone tell me why it will print to the webpage in the callback but not outside of the callback? Thanks :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var page = 1;
var groupIDs = [4271656,5896212,1188700];
var n=0;

while (n< groupIDs.length){

    $('#test').append("Group ID:" + "WHY WON'T YOU APPEND" + "<br/>");  

    getYammerJSON(page);

    function getData(returnData){
        $.each(returnData.users, function(key, value){
            if(value.email != undefined){
                $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
            }
        });
    }

    function getYammerJSON(page){
        $.get("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/" + groupIDs[n] + ".json?page=" + page, function(returnData) {
            getData(returnData);
            if(!returnData.more_available === true){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                page++;
                getYammerJSON(page);
            }
        });
    }
    n++;
    }
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">User Emails in Yammer Group IDs</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because your script is not able to find `$('#test')` div.

Comment: Why not? and do you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

because your script is not able to find `$('#test')` div. As you have not put any `.ready()` event block for `document` the script gets executed before `$('#test')` div appears.

So you need to wrap your code inside doc ready block:

```
$(function(){
   var page = 1;
   var groupIDs = [4271656,5896212,1188700];
   var n=0;

   while (n< groupIDs.length){

      $('#test').append("Group ID:" + "WHY WON'T YOU APPEND" + "<br/>");  

      getYammerJSON(page);

    function getData(returnData){
        $.each(returnData.users, function(key, value){
            if(value.email != undefined){
                $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
            }
        });
    }

    function getYammerJSON(page){
        $.get("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/" + groupIDs[n] + ".json?page=" + page, function(returnData) {
            getData(returnData);
            if(!returnData.more_available === true){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                page++;
                getYammerJSON(page);
            }
        });
    }
    n++;
    }
});
```

---

### Edits:

You can move your `append` in here:

```
function getData(returnData){
        $.each(returnData.users, function(key, value){
            if(value.email != undefined){
                $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
                $('#test').append("Group ID:" + "WHY WON'T YOU APPEND" + "<br/>"); // <----move it here.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jai, But the only problem is now that it fires the append before executing the script, so my output is like:

    User Emails in Yammer Group IDsGroup ID:WHY WON'T YOU     APPEND
    Group ID:WHY WON'T YOU APPEND
    Group ID:WHY WON'T YOU APPEND

and then the emails, I need it to separate between each iteration of n

Answer (score 0):

write your script at the bottom of page or put the test div at the top.
you are running your js code before the tag is even rendered ... it wont find div so it wont append anything

**IT NOT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS**

```
    <script>
$("#test").append("ghgh");
</script>

<div id = "test"> jj </div>
```

**IT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS**

```
<div id = "test"> jj </div>
    <script>
$("#test").append("ghgh");

</script>
```

EDIT 1:
If you really want to run your code first then append all the text in a string type variable and then at the end just add it the to value of div.

EDIT 2:

Like this

```
  <script>
for( condtion counter etc)
{
    str_var+= "your text";
 }   
    </script>
```

and then after running your srcipt

```
$("#test").text(str_var); or $("#test").val(str_var); or append
```

Comment: @Ali bean you can do either of the above suggestions! They both work!

Comment: Ok, but if you notice the script $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
 is happening as it runs, so if you append after the whole script is run, it will just put them all at the end

Comment: what ever the data that you want to append to the test div save it in a variable or an object if so and then put the data in the test div. Its as simple as it could get.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
var page = 1;
var groupIDs = [4271656,5896212,1188700];
var n=0;

while (n< groupIDs.length){

    $('#test').append("Group ID:" + "WHY WON'T YOU APPEND" + "<br/>");  

    getYammerJSON(page);

    function getData(returnData){
        $.each(returnData.users, function(key, value){
            if(value.email != undefined){
                $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
            }
        });
    }

    function getYammerJSON(page){
        $.get("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/" + groupIDs[n] + ".json?page=" + page, function(returnData) {
            getData(returnData);
            if(!returnData.more_available === true){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                page++;
                getYammerJSON(page);
            }
        });
    }
    n++;
   }
});
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">User Emails in Yammer Group IDs</div>
</body>
```

2.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">User Emails in Yammer Group IDs</div>
  
  
  <script>
var $ = jQuery;
var page = 1;
var groupIDs = [4271656,5896212,1188700];
var n=0;

while (n< groupIDs.length){

    $('#test').append("Group ID:" + "WHY WON'T YOU APPEND" + "<br/>");  

    getYammerJSON(page);

    function getData(returnData){
        $.each(returnData.users, function(key, value){
            if(value.email != undefined){
                $('#test').append(value.email + "<br/>");
            }
        });
    }

    function getYammerJSON(page){
        $.get("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/in_group/" + groupIDs[n] + ".json?page=" + page, function(returnData) {
            getData(returnData);
            if(!returnData.more_available === true){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                page++;
                getYammerJSON(page);
            }
        });
    }
    n++;
   }
</script>  
  
</body>
</html>
```